# Orbeon XPath getting checked values from checkboxes list to dropdown list

Tags: xpath, orbeon, liferay-7

I got a scrollable list of checkboxes from which I want to extract the checked values and insert them into a dropdown menu.

The list of checkboxes besides the static values it also receives dynamic content based on how the user interacts with the form.

I saw that the list of checkboxes saves the checkboxed items dynamically into the `instance('form-name')/control-name` but they are separated with space.

I thought that I make a `xxf:script` that splits them and then adds them to the dropdown menu but I think I over think it.

Is there a better way and also can someone provide some example code?

Comment: Is this for a form you're creating in Form Builder, or are you writing XForms "by hand"?

Comment: can you share your xml ?

Comment: @avernet I am using Form Builder but also editing the source code when I want something dynamic, also I am using version 4.10

Comment: @gtosto which part ? The whole XML has like 10k lines